# Use of "that" when proceeded by people, proper nouns, or pronouns

Tags: word-usage

"I admit that I am a student in college"

I came across this sentence in an online post one day when a comment below it corrected the user, saying "that" should not be used when it is preceded by people, proper nouns, or pronouns. Can someone explain this rule? Is there actually something wrong with this sentence? How should this sentence be corrected? Perhaps "I admit I am a student in college"?

When should "that" be used? In my first paragraph, would it have been wrong to say "...corrected the user, saying that "that" should not be..."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "rule" is right (as far as there are any rules in English): *that* should not be used when it is preceded by a word which refers to a person.

> *People that use words like this are wrong.

The reasoning is that *that* objectifies the person it references, and *who* should be used instead.

> People who use words like this are right.

However, in your example, *that* is not referencing a person; it is linking the admission to a fact, the fact that the writer is a student.

> I am a student in college.
>   I admit that I am a student in college.

Note that the "rule" uses the word *preceded*. In my example, *that* is preceded by the "person" noun *people*. In the quoted example in the question, *that* is preceded by a verb. *Admit* in this use actually **requires** *that*.

The commenter who objected to *that* in those circumstances hyper-corrected.

Comment: +1 The commenter indeed hyper-corrected, following a "rule" blindly - something that happens too often, alas.